# PC Restarts Randomly

Tags: hard-drive, memory, graphics-card, power-supply

I have a PC with the following configuration: AMD R7 2700, B450 Aorus Elite, GTX 1050 Ti 4GB, 16 GB DDR4, 240 + 480 GB SDD's, 500GB HDD, Super Flower Leadex 2 Gold 650W PSU.

I am facing the following problem: the PC restarts randomly, for example while I am listening musing, while I am playing games (like GTA5 or FarCry5), while I am browsing the internet.
Before I get the restart, the screen freezes for a few seconds and I cannot move the mouse cursor on the screen, but if I press the caps lock button, then the caps lock led on the keyboard lights up or it turns off.

I am getting in the Event Viewer the following error:
"The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly."

Event ID: 41

BugcheckCode 278

BugcheckParameter1 0xffff8e0159eab010

BugcheckParameter2 0x0

BugcheckParameter3 0x0

BugcheckParameter4 0x0

SleepInProgress 0

PowerButtonTimestamp 0

BootAppStatus 0

Checkpoint 41

ConnectedStandbyInProgress false

SystemSleepTransitionsToOn 23

CsEntryScenarioInstanceId 0

BugcheckInfoFromEFI true

CheckpointStatus 0

I tried the following, by looking on the internet using the information from the error: I updated the graphics driver but the problem persists and I uninstalled the graphics driver and I made a clean install  of the driver but the problem, also, persists.

Please let me know, what should I do in order to find the solution to my problem ?

Edit: I checked the temperatures while running OCCT, and the temperatures are good (the max temp is about 71 C, on the GPU and about 61 C on the CPU). Also I run a Windows memory test, and it finished successfully.

Comment: "SystemSleepTransitionsToOn 23"  <-- Update the BIOS on the computer, update Power Drive if there is one, and turn off (disable) Hibernation and Hybrid Sleep.

Comment: Hard freezes like this are usually either overheating, or memory related problems. Have you tried using a hardware monitoring app to see if it's heat related?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I checked the temperatures while running OCCT, and the temperatures are good (the max temp is about 71 C, on the GPU and about 61 C on the CPU). While gaming the temperatures are lower than during OCCT. Also I run a Windows memory test, and it finished successfully.

Comment: Try the solution I put in earlier.

Comment: I tried the solution @John said and now I am waiting to see if the restart happens again.

Comment: I tried the solution @John but the problem persist. This is a screenshot with the new error code: https://ibb.co/PxyQbNV

Comment: If driver updates to your existing installation do not fix this (and indeed change the error codes), then you likely now need to back up, reinstall Windows with all new drivers (except BIOS).

Comment: I reinstalled Windows with all new drivers @John , I removed one of the SSD and I replaced the old HDD with a new one, and I am getting the following error now: https://ibb.co/0FvCY7d

Comment: Not sure - it appears the computer is not fully compliant with Windows 10.  The only two things between Windows and running is (a) BIOS and (b) SSD driver.  Try again with those updates.

Comment: I updated bios to the latest version @John , and I also updated the ssd driver. I also installed a old driver for the graphics card, and I got the following error, while I was navigating through the Far Cry 5 video settings: https://ibb.co/ZV0sSKd